# Getting navigator.block is not a function while navigating to other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In a React project, I've created a popup modal which will be displayed when any user tries to do any changes in input field and navigate to other screen. It doesn't work as expected, hence gone through many posts to find the solution but, no luck. Please refer to code below:

useBlock.js

```
import {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext} from 'react-router-dom';
const useBlocker = (blocker, when = true) => {
    const navigator = useContext(NavigationContext).navigator
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!when)
            return;
        const unblock = navigator.block((tx) => { <-- This line is creating an issue
            const autoUnblockingTx = {
                ...tx,
                retry() {
                  unblock();
                  tx.retry();
                },
              };
            blocker(autoUnblockingTx);
        });
        return unblock;
    }, [navigator, blocker, when]);
}

export default useBlocker
```

useCallbackPrompt.js

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import useBlocker from './useBlocker';

const useCallbackPrompt = (when) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);
    const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState(null);
    const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = useState(false);
    const cancelNavigation = useCallback(() => {
        setShowPrompt(false);
    }, []);

    const handleBlockedNavigation = useCallback((nextLocation) => {
        if (!confirmedNavigation &&
            nextLocation.location.pathname !== location.pathname) {
            setShowPrompt(true);
            setLastLocation(nextLocation);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, [confirmedNavigation]);
    
    const confirmNavigation = useCallback(() => {
        setShowPrompt(false);
        setConfirmedNavigation(true);
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation) {
            navigate(lastLocation.location.pathname);
        }
    }, [confirmedNavigation, lastLocation]);
    useBlocker(handleBlockedNavigation, when);
    return [showPrompt, confirmNavigation, cancelNavigation];
}

export default useCallbackPrompt
```

So above are the 2 files which I'm using. In useBlocker.js file that particular line is actually causing the root issue. Please refer to the image below

[image]

I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`, Is this causing any issue? Any suggestions or modifications are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue using `react-router-dom@6.3.0`, but I could when bumping to `react-router-dom@6.4.0`. I suspect with a dependency specified as `^6.3.0` you've actually a more current version actually installed. If you like you can check the installed version by running `npm list react-router-dom` and verify for yourself.

It seems the navigation context has a mildly breaking change between v6.3.0 and v6.4.0. The v6.3.0 version is a history object ([source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.3.0/packages/react-router/lib/context.ts#L16)) while the v6.4.0 is a new navigation context object where `navigator` is a simpler interface ([source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/context.ts#L99-L121)).

### Solution 1 - Revert to previous version

You could revert back to `6.3.0` though by running `npm i -s react-router-dom@6.3.0` to install that exact version. Double-check your package.json file to ensure the entry is `"react-router-dom": "6.3.0"`.

### Solution 2 - Use the "real" `history` object

If you wanted to move forward with the newer RRD versions then an alternative I'd suggest is to use the `history@5` `history` object directly instead of trying to use the `react-router@6` `navigator`. RRDv6 was only ever exporting a subset of the `history` methods anyway.

1. Add `history@5` as a project dependency.

   ***IMPORTANT:** You will want to check what version `react-router-dom` is using and match if you can.*
2. Create and export a custom history object. `createBrowserHistory` for a BrowserRouter, `createHashHistory` for a HashRouter, etc.

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

   const history = createBrowserHistory();

   export default history;
   ```
3. Import your custom history object and the history router from RRD.

   ```
   import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
   import history from './history';

   ...

   <Router history={history}>
     <App />
   </Router>
   ```
4. Import your custom history object to use in your custom hooks.

   ```
   import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
   import history from "./history"; // <-- import

   const useBlocker = (blocker, when = true) => {
     useEffect(() => {
       if (!when) return;
       const unblock = history.block((tx) => { // <-- use history
         const autoUnblockingTx = {
           ...tx,
           retry() {
             unblock();
             tx.retry();
           }
         };
         blocker(autoUnblockingTx);
       });
       return unblock;
     }, [blocker, when]);
   };
   ```

   `useCallbackPrompt` is untouched.

   ```
   const useCallbackPrompt = (when) => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     const location = useLocation();
     const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);
     const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState(null);
     const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = useState(false);
     const cancelNavigation = useCallback(() => {
       setShowPrompt(false);
     }, []);

     const handleBlockedNavigation = useCallback(
       (nextLocation) => {
         if (
           !confirmedNavigation &&
           nextLocation.location.pathname !== location.pathname
         ) {
           setShowPrompt(true);
           setLastLocation(nextLocation);
           return false;
         }
         return true;
       },
       [confirmedNavigation]
     );

     const confirmNavigation = useCallback(() => {
       setShowPrompt(false);
       setConfirmedNavigation(true);
     }, []);
     useEffect(() => {
       if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation) {
         navigate(lastLocation.location.pathname);
       }
     }, [confirmedNavigation, lastLocation]);
     useBlocker(handleBlockedNavigation, when);
     return [showPrompt, confirmNavigation, cancelNavigation];
   };
   ```

Demo

[image: Edit getting-navigator-block-is-not-a-function-while-navigating-to-other-page]

Answer (score 2):

From v6.4.0 navigator.block is removed. You can find a workaround here: https://gist.github.com/MarksCode/64e438c82b0b2a1161e01c88ca0d0355.

Also, relevant discussion going on here. https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139#issuecomment-1262630360

Comment: The thread you linked just over a year old, can you link to the *relevant* part regarding this change to the navigator context so users don't need to scroll/search for it?

Comment: I've updated, thanks! @drew

Comment: Oh, wow... that thread turned into a real dumpster fire.

Answer (score 1):

In [v6.7.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/react-router%406.7.0) they added `unstable_useBlocker` and `unstable_usePrompt` and those are still there.

So you can either use `unstable_usePrompt` directly or if you want some custom component to be shown you can try to combine your custom solution with `unstable_useBlocker`.

I did this in my case:

```
export function usePrompt(when = true) {
  const blocker = unstable_useBlocker(when);

  useEffect(() => {
    // message in latest Chrome will be ignored anyway - it uses its own
    if (when) window.onbeforeunload = () => "Are you sure?";

    return () => {
      window.onbeforeunload = null;
    };
  }, [when]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (blocker.state === "blocked") {
      const element = document.createElement("div");
      element.setAttribute("id", "prompt-dialog-container");
      element.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

      const closePrompt = (state: boolean) => {
        if (element) {
          ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(element);
        }
        if (!state) {
          document.body.removeChild(element);
          blocker.reset();
        } else {
          blocker.proceed();
        }
      };

      document.body.appendChild(element);
      // just a modal with message "You have unsaved changes in this report. Do you want to save your changes?" and 2 buttons [Yes] and [No]
      ReactDOM.render(<ExitPrompt onYes={() => closePrompt(false)} onNo={() => closePrompt(true)} />, element);
    }
  }, [blocker]);
}
```